# ArcGIS Python query syntax

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I am struggling with running a simple piece of code using Python in ArcGIS field calculator. I suspect it could be a very simple error and need an extra set of eyes.

For summer months (Dec-Feb) and winter months (Jun-Aug) I would like to check for specific minimum and maximum values in my data and assign them a comment if the query is met. The code that I have written is given below, however, when running the code I get a syntax parsing error.

```py
def Reclass (tmeanJAN,tmeanFEB,tmeanDEC,tmeanJUN,tmeanJUL,tmeanAUG):
   if tmeanJAN and tmeanFEB and tmeanDEC = 28:
      return "Ideal maximum summer temperature"
   elif tmeanJAN and tmeanFEB and tmeanDEC = 18:
      return "Ideal minimum summer temperature"
   elif tmeanJUN and tmeanJUL and tmeanAUG  = 23:
      return "Ideal maximum winter temperature"
   elif tmeanJUN and tmeanJUL and tmeanAUG = 8:
      return "Ideal minimum winter temperature"
   else:
      return "N/A"
```

Called with:

```py
Reclass(!Int_tmeanJAN!, !Int_tmeanFEB!, !Int_tmeanDEC!, !Int_tmeanJUN!, !Int_tmeanJUL!, !Int_tmeanAUG!)
```

A sample of my dataset is provided in the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` should be `==`

`=` is for assigning a value to a variable, for example `a=10`

`==` is for comparing, `10==10` will be `True`

But your function wont work as intended:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 1

print a and c and b == 1
False
```

But:

```
print a and b and c == 1
True
```

`b` isnt 1, but it says `True`. You are asking `are a not null and b not null and c 1`, and that is True.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376516/check-if-multiple-variables-have-the-same-value) instead:

```
def Reclass (tmeanJAN,tmeanFEB,tmeanDEC,tmeanJUN,tmeanJUL,tmeanAUG):
   if all(temp==28 for temp in [tmeanJAN, tmeanFEB, tmeanDEC]):
      return "Ideal maximum summer temperature"
   elif all(temp==18 for temp in [tmeanJAN, tmeanFEB, tmeanDEC]):
      return "Ideal minimum summer temperature"
   elif all(temp==23 for temp in [tmeanJUN, tmeanJUL, tmeanAUG]):
      return "Ideal maximum winter temperature"
   elif all(temp==8 for temp in [tmeanJUN, tmeanJUL, tmeanAUG]):
      return "Ideal minimum winter temperature"
   else:
      return "N/A"
```